# .htaccess - arabic slugs

Tags: .htaccess, slug

The slug with me is not supporting Arabic and when I try to write in Arabic it deletes it and replaces it with `-cat`
so I want it to be supporting Arabic and I want to remove `-cat` from the whole file not just the category.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#Category
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9_-]+)-([0-9_-]+)-([0-9_-]+)$ cat1.php?id1=$2&id2=$3&id3=$4&id4=$5    [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9_-]+)-([0-9_-]+)$    cat1.php?id1=$2&id2=$3&id3=$4    [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9_-]+)$               cat1.php?id1=$2&id2=$3           [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$                          cat1.php?id1=$2                  [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  cat1.php?id1=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)--([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) cat1.php?id1=$3&id2=$4

RewriteRule ^cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  cat1.php?id1=$1&id2=$2
RewriteRule ^cat([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$                   cat1.php?id1=$1&v=3

RewriteRule ^itm([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-edit$              artikel.php?id=$1&create=edit
RewriteRule ^itm([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-create$            artikel.php?id=$1&create=created
RewriteRule ^itm([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$                   artikel.php?id=$1               [QSA]
RewriteRule ^a/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$               index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^b/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*?)$              kate.php?id=null

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=pagenotload
```

Comment: Well then you will need to start by allowing Arabic characters inside the character classes in the relevant places, because right now `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` only allows Classical Latin letters ...

Comment: How to do it
You can edit the code and send it to